# Insert contents of file at given line for multiple files, using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to find all files matching a pattern (`cs*.dat3`) in the current and sub-folders and insert a block of text, either from a file or from a bash variable, into a given line. It *could* also be after matching a pattern in the file instead of a given line, but I have

```
PRESSURE_RELIEF_PANELS
EXIT PRESSURE_RELIEF_PANELS
```

so the stuff would be put in twice. Luckily, the first `PRESSURE_RELIEF_PANELS` is always at line 32, so that can be utilized. My current take is this:

```
find . -name cs*.dat3 -exec sed '33iblah' {} \;
```

which outputs

```
PRESSURE_RELIEF_PANELS
blah
EXIT PRESSURE_RELIEF_PANELS
```

Now, instead of "blah", I want to insert a block of text. This text is stored in a file, so it could either be stored temporarily in a bash variable or it could be read into `sed` as a path or file somehow. I have not been able to find a good solution to this, since I haven't been able to combine the `sed`'s insert statement (`i`) with the filename statement (`r`).

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *read file* command with an address.  Saying:

```
sed '33rfile' input
```

would insert the file named `file` after line number 33 in the `input`.

You might be already aware that `r` is a GNU extension.

Quoting from the manual:

> `` `r FILENAME' ``
>
> ```
>  As a GNU extension, this command accepts two addresses.
>
>  Queue the contents of FILENAME to be read and inserted into the
>  output stream at the end of the current cycle, or when the next
>  input line is read.  Note that if FILENAME cannot be read, it is
>  treated as if it were an empty file, without any error indication.
>
>  As a GNU `sed' extension, the special value `/dev/stdin' is
>  supported for the file name, which reads the contents of the
>  standard input.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. For the record my final working command is `find . -name cs*.dat3 -exec sed -i '33r../text.dat' {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
find . -name cs*.dat3 -exec sed -i.bak '/^PRESSURE_RELIEF_PANELS$/r file.dat' '{}' \;
```

Where `file.dat` will have the data to be inserted.

Comment: This gives me the following error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: '^'`. What is the `^` for? First match or something?

Comment: Actually I missed `/` before `^` while copy/pasting.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense - this works as well. Does the `^` mean to match first occurrence only?

Comment: No `^` is line start anchor and `$` is line end anchor in regex. This is to make sure `PRESSURE_RELIEF_PANELS` is the only string in a line and we insert file content after this line.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I should really find the time to dig into regex.